# How to display search result by dropdown boxes in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having problem display search result by useing multiple dropdown boxes.

my Laravel Framework is 6.18.8

This is table stracture.

*id | name | type | wc | fc | yc | sc |*

User choose value of each select box and important thing is User MUST select 'WC' column value.

For example. A user choose below

- 'type' as w value
- 'wc' as N1 value (USER must select this column)
- 'fc' as f02 value
- 'yc' as yc1 value
- 'sc' as Z03 value

I would like to fetch above matched result. Could you please teach me how to write correct search function please?

**UPDATED** (Current blade file [Dear Makdous helps me])

**search.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('search') }}" class="form-image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="col-md-5">

                <strong>TYPE</strong>

                <select name="type" class="form-control">
                <option value="-" selected>-</option>
                <option value="j">j</option>
                <option value="w">w</option>
                </select>     

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <strong>wc</strong>
                <select name="wc" class="form-control">
                <option value="N0" selected>0</option>
                <option value="N1">1</option>
                <option value="N2">2</option>
                <option value="N3">3</option>

                </select>              

            </div>
             <div class="col-md-5">

                <strong>FC</strong>
                <select name="fc" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected>0</option>                   
                <option value="f01">f01</option>
                <option value="f02">f02</option>
                <option value="f03">f03</option>

                </select>              

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">

                <strong>YC</strong>
                <select name="yc" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected>0</option>                   
                <option value="yc1">yc1</option>
                <option value="yc2">yc2</option>

                </select>              

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">

                <strong>SC</strong>
                <select name="sc" class="form-control">
                <option value="Z01" selected>Z01</option>                   
                <option value="Z02" selected>Z02</option>
                <option value="Z03" selected>Z03</option>


                </select>              

            </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">

            <br/>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>

        </div>

    </div>


</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function order(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [            
                'wc' => 'required'
                ]);

        $images = ImageGallery::where('type', 'like', '%')
            ->where('wc', 'like', '%')
            ->where('fc', 'like', '%')
            ->where('yc', 'like', '%')
            ->where('sc', 'like', '%')            
             $result = compact('images');

        return view('result',compact('result'));
    }
```

**WEB.php**

```
// search section
Route::post('search', 'ImageGalleryController@order');
Route::get('search', 'ImageGalleryController@search');
```

UPDATE (Current code [Dear Makdous helps me])

**Controller**

```
public function order(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [            
        'wc' => 'required'
    ]);      

    $images = ImageGallery::where(['type',$request->type],
        ['wc',$request->wc],
        ['fc',$request->fc],
        ['yc',$request->yc],
        ['sc',$request->sc])->get();              
    return view('search',compact('images'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you put `name` on each drop box in the view file, You can access them like this:

```
$data = $request->all();
$images = ImageGallery::where([['type',$request->$data['type']],
            ['wc',$request->$data['wc']],
            ['fc',$request->$data['fc']],
            ['yc',$request->$data['yc']],
            ['sc',$request->$data['sc']]])->get();
```

Comment: Dear @makdous I really appreciate your help. May I ask one more things? I got This error "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD." Seems like I wrote wrong at web.php. Do me a favor Could you please teach me correct code?

Comment: Dear @makdous And I got. ErrorException  Array to string conversion. now. If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: where are you getting the `ErrorException Array to string conversion`?

Comment: Dear @makdous  Thank you very much for keep helping me.
"ErrorException Array to string conversion " error is gone now.
and I did replace view code . Now I got this error.
Route [search] not defined. (View: resources\views\search.blade.php)

Comment: try `form action="{{ url('/search') }}" class="form-image-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Dear @makdous Thank you very much again. Route [search] not defined. error message is gone now. but I got "ErrorException Array to string conversion error again. I'm guessing my Controller public function search is wrong. Could you teach me how to write please?

Comment: Dear @makdous  Thank you. I still got same error "ErrorException Array to string conversion"

Comment: I can't quite figure it out, Try asking a separate question about this problem, Maybe someone who's familiar with this error can assist you.

Comment: Dear @makdous Thank you very much. I'm so happy you've been helping me.